# Temporary Job Ending

Tags: colleagues

I really enjoyed working with my school's administrative(Principle, Asst.Principle, Head Secretary, and Liason for Students and Parents)staff. After working 5 mos. the school year is coming to a close and my temp position will be ending. What would be an appropriate parting gift.

Comment: This question is too broad for us to answer, as the answer can change depending on where you are in the world.  I would recommend [googling this topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=appropriate+parting+gift+for+coworkers&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab)

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like all of those people are above you.  In the US at least, gifts should flow down, not up, which means that giving them a gift is not appropriate.  You don't give gifts to people who earn more than you, except in rare cases (baby or wedding gifts, for instance).

However, giving them a card with a heartfelt thanks for something you have learned from them, or some other benefit to working with them, is never inappropriate.

Comment: Agreed for a Western workplace, but expectations might be different in other cultures.

Comment: @GeoffreyBrent oh, very good point!